# Internet complaining about Outlook.com

Tags: internet

I have a Galaxy SIII Neo. I use [Outlook.com](http://hotmail.com/) as an email server, and every time I reload it, Internet complains about security issues. How do I tell Internet Outlook is safe and to stop annoying me with that message?

**Edit:**
First of all, it doesn't *always* happen, and I can't reproduce it now. It seems to be correlated with auto-reloading after a long time off the Internet app. It had an analogue on my older mobile, with two fundamental differences:

1. I have the impression it happened *much* less often;
2. The old version had a "Continue" button underneath, meaning I could just tap and ignore the problem, though it sometimes popped up again shortly afterwards.

**Update:**
I got it again. Here it is:

[image]

«You have attempted to reach col126.mail.live.com, but the server provided a certificate issued by an entity that is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This may mean that the server has generated its own security credentials, which Chromium cannot rely on for security information, or an attacker may be trying to intercept your communications.

You cannot proceed because the website operator has requested heightened security for this domain.»

1. What exactly has «my computer» to do with this since the computer *doesn't* complain at all (though it used to…)?
2. And Chromium? What is it? I knew about Chrome, but Chromium is new.

Here is the analogue I had on the older mobile, as gotten on my mother's:

[image]

My mother's mobile speaks Italian, so let me translate this:

«Security notice

Problems with this site's security certificate

This certificate was not emitted by a reliable organism»

(buttons "COntinue", "See certificate" and "Cancel"). The original English is probably closer to something like «issued by a trusted authority».

Comment: What message do you see?

Comment: @danhulme something about security issues and the site maybe creating its own credentials. I'll add a screenshot once I get home. :)

Comment: What are you using to access your email? The Browser, Email app, GMail app?

Comment: It's called Internet.

Comment: @DanHulme see the edit too.

Comment: So the default internet browser then. Why not try the included Email app?

Comment: I'd look through the internet settings for Samsung's default internet browsers, but I don't own a Samsung (stock Android's default browser is Chrome) and I'm not encountered such an issue there with my Outlook account.

Comment: @TrishLing because I didn't really know it existed :). Anyway I would like to see my mails instead of a bunch of empty folders as I see now. How do I download the mails? And I remember I once set up Mail on my computer and it moved mails around online, which I definitely _don't_ want. Do I risk that and how do I avoid it if so?

Comment: See the update everyone: I got it again. It really seems linked with auto-reloading Hotmail after a long time outside the internet app.

Comment: It has become much less frequent, but I'd still like to know how to completely eliminate this behaviour and what the message means.